# Name for scheme and host of URL

Tags: computer-networks

Is there a specific name when we refer to just the scheme and host of URL, for example `http://localhost` of the URL `http://localhost:8080/help` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the URL spec from the WHATWG](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-writing), the combination of scheme and host is a special case of what is called an **absolute-URL string**. Such a string is (in your case) a **URL-scheme string** matching a **special scheme** (e.g.  `http`), followed by `://` and a **valid host string** (e.g. `localhost`), *optionally* followed by a `:` with a **URL-port string** (e.g. `8080`), which is again *optionally* followed by **path-absolute-URL string** (e.g. `/help`).

As you can see, your second string is also called an absolute-URL string by the WHATWG spec. So there seems to be no official name for the combination of only the scheme and a host. In some sense, the scheme+host does not use any of the options available, so you could perhaps call it a *minimal absolute-URL string*.